# Different counters, same array. Array elements not changing. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, counter

I'm trying to have a user enter a number, and then have double check that they haven't already entered that particular number. I thought storing the user entered number in an array using one counter and then checking that same array with a for loop controlled counter would do the trick, but when I use the for loop counter in the array elements, it seems to always be zero. Can someone point me in the right direction here? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int guess[101] = { 0 };
    int count = 0;
    int check = 0;


    while (guess[count] != 1) {
        count++;
        cout << "Enter an integer." << endl;
        cin >> guess[count];
        if (guess[count] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        for (check = 0; check < count; check++) {
            cout << guess[check] << endl;
            if (guess[count] = guess[check]) {
                cout << "You already guessed " << guess[check] << ". Try a different integer between 1 and 100.\n" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (guess[count] == guess[check]) double equal to should be used for comparison.

Comment: doh. Thanks. I was changing the element back to zero with each iteration. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

if (guess[count] == guess[check]) double equal to should be used for comparison.